# CreateFileW GetLastError Returns 2

Tags: c++, file, registry

```
void * hFile = CreateFileW
(
    L"\\\\.\\OurFile",        // name of the write
    GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
    0,                      // do not share
    NULL,                   // default security
    CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
    NULL
);

if (!hFile || hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   std::cout << "hFile GetLastError(): 0x" << std::hex << GetLastError() << std::endl;
   std::getchar();
}
```

My code above is attempting to create a file. But the weird thing is, GetLastError() returns 2 somehow? I check Microsofts documentation and 2 gets returned if the file does not exist. But i am trying to create a file and not open an existing one. If anyone has a solution please let me know. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Which directory is the path `\\.\OurFile` supposed to point to? The path doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file `If you're working with Windows API functions, you should use the "\\.\" prefix to access devices only and not files.`

Comment: `L"\\\\.\\OurFile"` doesn't look right: I suspect *PATH* is the reason you're getting Errno(2): File not found.  ALSO:  Since you're always trying to "create", you should consider CREATE_ALWAYS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea